# Django-Attributes of model displayed in admin differ from what I got in other method

Tags: django

I used `update_or_create` method to change the model attribute but I noticed that change was not reflected as I expected it to.

While examining what is wrong, I noticed that, oddly, the value of the attribute when listed on the admin page was changed correctly.

I tried to get the object and check its attributes using various other methods, but obviously change wasn't reflected.

e.g.:

```
obj = SomeModel(pk=x) => obj.some_field  
obj = get_object_or_404 => obj.__dict__
```

In both methods, an `obj` with the same `pk` exists certainly, but each field is `None`.

What is going on?
Please help me...

Roughly, this is my code.

```
# in models.py
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    name = Field(primary_key=True) 
    other = Fields
# in forms.py
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    name = Fields
    other = Fields
# in views.py 
class CreateView(generic.View):
-------------------
    def post(self, request):
        if form.is_valid():
            dic = form.cleaned_data
            update_model(dic) #this come from manipulate.py
# in manipulate.py
def update_model(dic):
    updated = SomeClass(dic)
    new_dic = updated.__dict__
    SomeModel.objects.update_or_create(name=name, defaults=new_dic)

# in somefile.py => This is for calculation and validation.
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, dic):
        for k, v in dic.items():
            setattr(self ,k, v)
        self.some_validation_and_calculation()
    def some_validation_and_calculation():
--------------------------------
```

Comment: Did you perhapse define the `save` method on `SomeModel` and forgot to call the `super`?

Comment: please provide the actual code or at least more detail. How can you be sure that the `pk` exist when all fields are `None`?

Comment: @bonidjukic Thank you. But, I believe `update_or_create` include `save`. 
 Isn't this? (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/)

Comment: @alfonso.kim Thank you. I'm trying to explain more detail but this may take time. Sorry to have kept you waiting. Sorry, correctly, all fields except `pk` is `None`. I checked this to `print` `obj.__dict__`

Comment: Can you explain why you are doing any of this? Why have you written the `update_model` function in the first place? ModelForms already know how to update a model; pass an `instance` parameter on instantiation, and then call `save()`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I want to make an application that mimics blockchain. And because calculation and validation for that is complicated, I avoided writing directly. Also, the classes for that existed before used in Django, and I wanted to easily divert them to Django app. But it may be a foolish way actually.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I'm sorry I took time due to my rudimentary mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I was making a very stupid and rudimentary mistake. Instead of `obj = SomeModel.objects.get (pk = x)`, I created a new object using `obj = SomeModel (pk = x)`.